# Converting list of dates/times from GMT to PST

Tags: command-line, bash, date

If I run the command by itself it seems to be working fine.  As example using:

```
date --date='TZ="PST" Sun Jan 01 05:00:10 2017'
```

Sat Dec 31 21:00:10 PST 2016

However, I'm trying to use an input file with a list of dates/times and having issues with all the quotes and can't seem to get it working.  My input file (example name dates.input looks like:

```
$ cat dates.input 
Sun Jan 01 06:49:33 2017
Sun Jan 01 05:44:17 2017
Sun Jan 01 05:43:23 2017
Sun Jan 01 05:39:13 2017
Sun Jan 01 05:00:10 2017
```

The command I'm having issues with is:

```
while read i; do "date --date='TZ="PST" ${i}'"; done < dates.input
```

which gives

```
bash: date --date='TZ=PST Sun Jan 01 06:49:33 2017': command not found...
bash: date --date='TZ=PST Sun Jan 01 05:44:17 2017': command not found...
bash: date --date='TZ=PST Sun Jan 01 05:43:23 2017': command not found...
bash: date --date='TZ=PST Sun Jan 01 05:39:13 2017': command not found...
bash: date --date='TZ=PST Sun Jan 01 05:00:10 2017': command not found...
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to get this working?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an example, let's pick this value for `i`:

```
$ i='Sun Jan 01 06:49:33 2017'
```

Now, let's run the command in your loop:

```
$ "date --date='TZ="PST" ${i}'"
bash: date --date='TZ=PST Sun Jan 01 06:49:33 2017': command not found
```

As one can see, putting quotes around a command and its arguments confuses the shell.  Try instead:

```
$ date --date="TZ=\"PST\" ${i}"
Sat Dec 31 22:49:33 PST 2016
```

The above succeeds.

After placing this command within the loop, the loop now works:

```
$ while read i; do date --date="TZ=\"PST\" ${i}"; done < dates.input
Sat Dec 31 22:49:33 PST 2016
Sat Dec 31 21:44:17 PST 2016
Sat Dec 31 21:43:23 PST 2016
Sat Dec 31 21:39:13 PST 2016
Sat Dec 31 21:00:10 PST 2016
```

Comment: `read` skips the file's last line if it doesn't end in a newline, I suggest: `while IFS='' read -r i || [[ -n "$i" ]]; do date -d "TZ=\"PST\" $i"; done <dates.input`